# Can I contribute a wallpaper to elementary OS?

Tags: themes

I am actually new to elementary OS and i wanted to contribute a wallpaper to elementary OS.
I have the image and here is it,

[image: here is the image created]

What to do next ?
Actually i did just make the image and dropped it here.
Do i need to make a license or contact elementary OS?
Or what?
I am really confused.
If i need to edit anything tell me please.
Thanks.
Sorry for any misspells or mistakes.

Comment: This is so cool. Appreciated. I have voted up this one for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a pull request on the relevant Github repo [elementary/wallpapers](https://github.com/elementary/wallpapers). I see plenty of user contributed wallpapers there.

---

> ### To submit a wallpaper
>
> 1. Make sure your wallpaper is openly-licensed and okay for commercial
>      use
> 2. Fork the project and add the wallpaper
> 3. Add license info to the debian/copyright file
> 4. Add artist exif metadata using command exiftool -artist="Vincent van
>      Gogh" The\ Starry\ Night.jpg
> 5. Create a pull request.
>
> Very few pull requests will be accepted